# Google Apps Script - copy adjacent cell if not blank; can't get to copy entire column

Tags: google-apps-script

First, let me apologize for the unorganized mess this code is. I'm a total n00b and work mostly off of slicing and dicing other people's code I find online to achieve what I'm trying to do.

With that said, my overall goal is to manipulate raw data. Here are the steps:

1. Paste unorganized and raw data in spreadsheet, then run the following script;
2. If cell is not blank in column B, copy cell contents from column B and C to first empty row in column A. ***===> This part of the code works perfectly.***
3. If cell is not blank in column C, copy cell contents to adjacent cell in column B. ***===> This is the part of the code I'm having trouble with. It copies the first instance and does not copy the rest.***

Here is the code as it stands now:

```js
function dataParse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var targetValues = [];
  var targetValue = [];
  var range = ss.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol);
  var range1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range1.getColumn();
  var row = range1.getRow();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  var activeRow = 0;



  for (row in data) {
    if (data[row][1] !=''){
      var tempvalue = [data[row][1], data[row][2]];
      targetValues.push(tempvalue);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1 , targetValues.length, 2).setValues(targetValues);
  
  for (row in data1) {
    if (data1[row][2] !=''){
      var tempervalue = [data[row][2]];
      targetValue.push(tempervalue);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(row, col+1, targetValue.length, 1).setValues(targetValue);
}
```

I've tried guess/check to change many things to see if I'll get the result I'm looking for, but to no avail; hence why I'm here.

I'm sure it's something ridiculously small, but I'm not savvy enough to even see what the issue could be.

*Any* assistance is appreciated!!! Let me know if you need a sample sheet to see what I'm trying to explain and I'll make one. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copyMyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range=sh.getDataRange();
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if(data[i][1]){
      data[firstEmptyCell(data,0)][0]=data[i][1] + ' ' + data[i][2];
    }
    if(data[i][2]){
      data[i][1]=data[i][2];
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}

function firstEmptyCell(dataA,index){
  var vA=dataA;
  for(var i=0;i<dataA.length;i++){
    if(!vA[i][index]){
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet before:

[image]

Sheet after:

[image]

Comment: This solved my issue! You are amazing; thank you Cooper!!